# Error in deserializing body of request message for operation in WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xsd, namespaces

The error message when I try to send a SOAP message to the service is:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Anforderungsnachricht für Vorgang "executeJob". (Fehlerdetail ist gleich Ein ExceptionDetail, vermutlich erstellt durch IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=TRUE, mit dem Wert:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Anforderungsnachricht für Vorgang "executeJob". ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Fehler im XML-Dokument. ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Namespacepräfix 'xsd' wurde nicht definiert.
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToXmlQualifiedName(String value, Boolean decodeName)
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.GetXsiType()
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String name, String ns, String& fixupReference)
   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPortaladapterWebservice.Read1_AntragsdatensatzBean()
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializatio...).
```

The namespace prefix xsd seems to not be defined. I can't figure out how to solve this issue. I tried to add the xsd namespace to my service but it isn't showing up anywhere.

Comment: An exception message in English can be understood by more people.

Comment: Error deserializing the message body. Namespace 'xsd' is not defined.

Comment: Need to see an [mcve].  If the error is `Namespace 'xsd' is not defined.` then probably the request itself is not valid XML.  Have you checked with fiddler?